# What is the functionality of --pause flag in rosbag play cmd?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across an application where --pause flag argument was used in rosbag play cmd . I checked the wiki it says it starts the ros bag in paused mode . I was wondering what passed mode means.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362131/what-is-the-functionality-of---pause-flag-in-rosbag-play-cmd-?/) by [Shiva_uchiha](https://answers.ros.org/users/37455/shiva_uchiha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2020-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-09-23**:
a few lines before it says:

```
Additionally, during playing, you can pause at any time by pressing space. When paused, you can step through messages by pressing s.
```

I suppose it will be that

**Comment by [Shiva_uchiha](https://answers.ros.org/users/37455/shiva_uchiha/) on 2020-09-23**:
got it (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means the replay is paused. So it does not publish anything. You have to unpause it (in the terminal by pressing the space key, usually) to have it play...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1